# If $\{x_n=y_n + z_n\}$ converges, do $\{y_n\}$ and $\{z_n\}$ converge in Banach space?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, ||\cdot ||)$ be a Banach space such that $X=Y \oplus Z$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subspaces of $X$, such that every $x\in X$ can be uniquely written as $x=y+z$, $y\in Y, z \in Z$. Then $Y$ and $Z$ are both Banach spaces.  My question is:

If $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}= \{y_n+z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ converges to $0$, does it imply that both $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{ z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to $0$? If yes, how can it be proved, and if it's not the case, is there some counterexample? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If every vector in *X* can be written *uniquely* as a sum of representatives from each subspace, then this is not only a sum but a *direct* sum.

Comment: I edited, changed $+$ to $\bigoplus$. If we take $z_n= -y_n$, where $\{y_n\}$ diverges,  then $x_n=0$, and  $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$, but then $ 0 = y_n + (-y_n)$. Does it contradict assumption that $0$ can be uniquely written as $y+z$, for some $y\in Y, z \in Z$?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn’t work as a counterexample, because of the reason you stated. Unless the $y_n$ are all $0$, we can’t say that $-y_n$ is in $Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the operator $T\colon X\to X$ given by $T(y + z) = y$. We are using the fact that $X = Y\oplus Z$ to guarantee that this is well-defined.

Prove that the graph of $T$ is closed in $X\times X$. Then it follows that $T$ is continuous by the closed graph theorem for Banach spaces. By continuity, $T(x_n) = y_n$ converges to $T(0) = 0$.

Now we know that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ are convergent sequences (to $0$), and $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}} = (x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}}- (y_n)_{n\in\mathbf{N}} $ is too.